Intellij Gitlab Push rejected
I'm keep getting an error whenever I try to push. How to solve this?
Total 23 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.corp.test.com/TestTask/generic-concurrent-task-queue.git'
To https://gitlab.corp.test.com/TestTask/generic-concurrent-task-queue.git
!   refs/heads/main:refs/heads/main [remote rejected] (pre-receive hook declined)
Done


The Gitlab repository you are trying to push has the main branch protected. Only certain people can push to protected branches.
The response from the GitLab server states this.
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project.

If you think you should have access to push check with the admin.
Ref: Protected branches
